# DuplicateWidgetID: with st.button widgets with key='predict' for a image classification problem in Streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, streamlit, image-classification

I'm trying to write a web app, which will offer the user to input an image, select a deep learning model and click the Get a prediction button to classify the image as 'human detected' or 'no human detected' (it is a binomial classification problem).

I've got this error.
[image]

Below is my code with Streamlit, which gives me the error.

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


st.title("Binary Human Detection Web App")
# loading images
def load_image(uploaded_file):

    image = uploaded_file.resize((224,224))
    im_array = np.array(image)/255 # a normalised 2D array                
    im_array = im_array.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)   # to shape as (1, 224, 224, 3)
    return im_array


st.sidebar.subheader("Select a Model")
model_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Model", ("CNN", "ResNet50"))


if st.button("Try with the Default Image"):
    image = Image.open('C:/Users/maria/Jupiter_Notebooks/Dataset_Thermal_Project/Camera_videos/Images_3sec_newdata_v2/oneman/image21.jpg')
    st.subheader("Human is detected")
    st.image(image) 

# predicting images

if model_name == 'CNN':
    st.write("Try out the CNN model with the default image or upload an image")

    if st.sidebar.button("Get prediction", key='predict'):

        st.subheader("Upload an image file")
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a JPG image file", type=["jpg", "jpeg"])

        if uploaded_file is not None: 
            image = load_image(Image.open(uploaded_file))
            st.image(image)
            st.subheader("CNN Results")
            model_cnn = load_model("C:/Users/.../Camera_videos/Saved_models/cnn_model.h5")
            model_cnn_ = tf.keras.models.Model(model_cnn.inputs, model_cnn.outputs)

            pred_label = model_cnn_.predict(image)[0] 


#if model_name == 'ResNet50':
else:
    st.write("Try out the ResNet50 model with the default image or upload an image")
    if st.sidebar.button("Get prediction", key='predict'):

        st.subheader("Upload an image file")
        uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a JPG image file", type=["jpg", "jpeg"])

        if uploaded_file is not None: 
            image = load_image(Image.open(uploaded_file))
            st.image(image)
            st.subheader("ResNet50 Results")
            model_resnet = load_model("C:/Users/.../Camera_videos/Saved_models/model_resnet.h5")
            model_resnet_ = tf.keras.models.Model(model_resnet.inputs, model_resnet.outputs)
         
            pred_label = model_resnet_.predict(image)[0]  

            st.write('Human is detected') if pred_label>0.5 else  st.write('No human is detected')
```

I have also tried writing this code in a different way, but I dont know how to pass the 'uploaded_file' i.e. the file supplied by the user, into my initialize_model() function.

```
...
# loading images
def load_image(uploaded_file):

    image = uploaded_file.resize((224,224))
    im_array = np.array(image)/255 # a normalised 2D array                
    im_array = im_array.reshape(-1, 224, 224, 3)   # to shape as (1, 224, 224, 3)
    return im_array

st.sidebar.subheader("Select a NN Model")
model_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Model", ("CNN", "ResNet50", "VGG16"))

# predicting images
def initialize_model(model_name, image):
    if model_name == 'CNN':
        st.write("Try out the CNN model with the default image or upload an image")

        if st.sidebar.button("Get prediction", key='predict'):
            st.subheader("CNN Results")
            model_cnn = load_model("C:/Users/.../Camera_videos/Saved_models/cnn_model.h5")
            model_cnn_ = tf.keras.models.Model(model_cnn.inputs, model_cnn.outputs)

         #   image = load_image(Image.open(image))

            pred_label = model_cnn_.predict(image)[0] 


    if model_name == 'ResNet50':
        if st.sidebar.button("Get prediction", key='predict'):
            st.subheader("ResNet50 Results")
            model_resnet = load_model("C:/Users/.../Camera_videos/Saved_models/model_resnet.h5")
            model_resnet_ = tf.keras.models.Model(model_resnet.inputs, model_resnet.outputs)

            #image = load_image(uploaded_file)
           
            pred_label = model_resnet_.predict(image)[0]  



if st.button("Try with the Default Image"):
    d_image = Image.open('C:/Users/.../oneman/image21.jpg')
    st.image(d_image)
     st.subheader("Human is detected")
    st.image(initialize_model(model_name,d_image))


st.subheader("Upload an image file")
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a JPG image file", type=["jpg", "jpeg"])

if uploaded_file is not None: 
    sel_image = load_image(Image.open(uploaded_file))
    st.image(sel_image)
```

Can anyone help me with this problem? thank you for reading it.

Comment: Does `initialize_model() ` work  properly  when you don't  use `st.file_uploader`?

Answer (score 0):

Every button should have a **unique**  key value and you have multiple  buttons  with  same key value.

```py
st.sidebar.button("Get prediction", key='predict_btn1'): # make key value unique
```